# Operational priority calculation

Tags: statistics

I'm new to statistics, so bear with me with silly mistakes.

Suppose, there are 2 operations to complete a task.

- Operation1 takes 12 mins and the success probability is 1/2
- Operation2 takes 6 minutes, but the success rate is 1/6
- There are only two possible outcomes after any operation completed. Either the task done successfully or not. In case of unsuccessful completion, next operation have to start from the beginning once again.

You can run both operations (not simultaneously) 1 after 1 & only once.
What'll the priority of running the operation to get the actual task done in least time?

(**confession**: the person who asked me this question gave me the answer as Operation1 have higher priority even though it takes longer time but better success rate. but, cared not to give the explanation)

This problem becomes complicated when you have to prioritize such "***n***" number of operations with their different own success probability.
Any clue to calculate priority for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What interests us is the expected time we need.

When we do Operation $1$ first, we are successful after $12$ minutes with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, otherwise we require $18$ minutes. We therefore expect the process to take $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 12 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 18 = 15$ minutes on average.

When we do Operation $2$ first, we are successful after $6$ minutes with probability $\frac{1}{6}$, otherwise we require $18$ minutes. We expect the process to take $\frac{1}{6} \cdot 6 + \frac{5}{6} \cdot 18 = 16$ minutes.

Therefore doing Operation $1$ first will save us a minute.

Comment: Hi McFry. Amazing explanation. Just one more silly question. What happens if there is a third operation with time 8 minutes & success rate of 2/9? The O1 will run out after 2nd iteration. right?

Comment: In this case we need to do Operation $1$ first. Like that, no matter whether we do Operation $2$ or $3$ next, we expect to use $18.333\ldots$ minutes.

Comment: Can you please explain 18.333...???

Comment: Suppose we do Operation $1$, then $2$, then $3$. With probability $1/2$ we need to do only operation $1$ and use $12$ minutes. With probability $1/12$ (a sixth of the remaining half probability) we are finished after operation $2$, after $18$ minutes. With probability $5/12$ we need to do all three operations, taking $26$ minutes in total. On average this gives us $18.333\ldots$ minutes. We get the same result when we do Operation $1$, then $3$, then $2$. However if we use a different order, we will need more time on average.